# How to get MSSQL SERVER error messages defined on a trigger in PHP - PDO?

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

I have a PHP 5.38, XAMP 1.7.7 web service that queries a MSSQL server 2014,  using PDO.

Everithing works fine except the fact that I cannot capture in PHP,  the error messages that MSSQL SERVER throws,  which were created as Triggers.

Using try catch,  is limited to the scope of Exceptions,  not this kind of error message.

Tried to use "mssql_get_last_message", however I get and error message from PHP itself which doesn't recognizes this function.

How can I capture MSSQL server triggered error messages?

Answer (score 0):

**[PDO::errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)**

> PDO::errorInfo — Fetch extended error information associated with the
>   last operation on the database handle

```
<?php
/* Provoke an error -- bogus SQL syntax */
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('query');
if (!$stmt) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}
?>
```

**[PDO::errorCode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php)**

> PDO::errorCode — Fetch the SQLSTATE associated with the last operation
>   on the database handle

**[PDOStatement::errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php)**

> PDOStatement::errorInfo — Fetch extended error information associated
>   with the last operation on the statement handle

**[PDOStatement::errorCode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php)**

> PDOStatement::errorCode — Fetch the SQLSTATE associated with the last
>   operation on the statement handle

Comment: your answer returns MSSQL driver error messages,  what I need is to get custom errors triggered by MSSQL server,  those are not generic coded errors, they are custom errors.

Comment: When forcing an error: PDO::errorInfo():
Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 0
    [2] => Unknown Attribute (setAttribute[0] at (null):0)
    [3] => IM001
)

Comment: I'm not familiar with ms-sql servers , but [this](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php#pdo-sqlsrv.constants) may be helpful .